# Check if there is any mark after variable value with java regex

Tags: java, regex, variables

```
String url = /aaa/bbbb/cake/123_asd&%?/reg ex+
String variable =cake    
if(url.matches(".*"+variable"+'.$'")
```

I would like to know if there is any mark after variable. This gives me syntax error. Any ide what is the correct syntax?

Comment: try `if(url.matches("'.*'"+variable+"'.$'")`

Comment: what do you mean by `any mark` after variable?

Comment: @nafas I mean letters, numbers, spaces what ever.

Comment: So you want to know if there is anything after variable. Then you simply check if(url.endsWith(variable))

Comment: Do you want to know if there is any word after `variable` on the line where you found it, or do you want to know if there are any characters left after `variable` in the word you found?

Comment: You can insert a word end `\>` or a word boundary `\b` in a regular expression. (Not sure which one is implemented in java.)

Comment: Try `if(url.matches(".*"+Pattern.quote(variable)+".*$")) {...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another way which will display the contents of the URL **after** the variable:

```
// Your link string
String link  = "/aaa/bbbb/cake/123_asd&%?/reg ex+";

// Your delimiter 
String variable = "cake"; 

// Variable to hold the string contents located
// after the delimiter
String textAfterVar = "";    

/*
To fill the textAfterVar string variable we're 
going to use the Pattern Matcher method and a small 
regex expression for obtaining the string portion  
found after our delimiter.
Here we establish our pattern to use and place it into
a variable conveniently named pattern....  */
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i).*(" + variable + ")+(.*)");
/*
Breakdown of the expression string: ".*(" + variable + ")+(.*)"
(?i)        Ignore letter case. Remove if you want to be case sensitive.
.*          Match any character 0 or more times (except newline).
(           Group 1 Start...
+variable+  The string variable which holds our delimiter string. 
            Will be held as Group 1.
)           Group 1 End.
+           Match one or more of the previous item which in this case is 
            the contents of our variable.
(           Group 2 Start... This group will be any text after the delimiter.
.*          Match any character 0 or more times (except newline).
)           Group 2 End.  */

/*
We now run the pattern through the matcher method to
see if there is a match to our regex expression.  */
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(link);

// See if the matcher method finds a match to our expression.
// If so place the contents into the textAfterVar string variable.
if (matcher.find()) { textAfterVar = matcher.group(2); }

// Display the contents of the textAfterVar string 
// variable in output console (pane).
System.out.println(textAfterVar);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if your String is too long you can try to use `find()` instead, this way you don't have to match the whole String, but instead what you are interested in (it also makes `Regex` easier to read too).

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(variable) + "[^$]");  //find variable + anything but end of line

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(url);

    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("matched");
    }else{
        System.out.println("not matched");
    }
```

Example:

**INPUT1**:

```
String url="/aaa/bbbb/cake/123_asd&%?/reg ex+";
String variable="cake";
```

**OUTPUT1**:

> matched

**INPUT2**:

```
String url="/aaa/bbbb/cake/123_asd&%?/reg ex+.";
String variable="ex+.";
```

**OUTPUT2**:

> not matched